# How to configure hotkeys to release focus with qemu / virt-manager

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, qemu, virt-manager

I'm using `virt-manager` on a Linux Mint 19.2 system to run a Windows 10 guest in `qemu/kvm`. For video, I'm using *splice/ qlx*. I can release the focus by pressing the <kbd>left ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>left alt</kbd> keys together. I want to change this to only the <kbd>right ctrl</kbd> key. Is it possible at all? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add a virtual USB tablet device to your VM, you probably don't need to deal with explicit grab/ungrab. But virt-manager let's you change the grab combination via Edit->Preferences->Console->Grab Keys setting

Comment: Thank you! I must have been blind....

Comment: Super useful answer, thanks!